Implementation of creating dynamic subdomains in Astrojs
Can you suggest options for implementing dynamic subdomains for a site on astro (SSR)?
**1.**The first question in development is how to create local hosts of subdomains?
**2.**Is it possible not to create separate sites for each subdomain and place everything in one project? And what would it look like in a routing implementation?
**3.**Well, as for the deployment, I think that according to the subdomain it will be possible to implement the delivery of the necessary content, but if there is something to add, I would be glad.
There is nothing in the documentation about this
https://docs.astro.build/

#1 you can use https://nip.io/

Where and how do you plan to deploy? static-site, or..?
